# Extension of a result about measurable, additive functionals

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, measure-theory

Let $W$ be a set, and let $v$ be a finitely additive probability measure on $2^W$.

Equip $2^W$ with the Borel sigma-algebra $\mathcal{B}$ generated by the sub-basic sets of the form $\{a: w \in a\}$ and $\{a: w \notin a\}$, where $w \in W$.

I am interested in characterizing those probability measures $P$ on $(2^W, \mathcal{B})$ such that for ($P$-almost) all $a \in 2^W$,
$$P(\{w \in 2^W: v(w \cap a)=v(a)v(w)\})=1. \tag{1}$$
Intuitively, this is saying that for all $a$, almost every $P$-randomly selected subset $w$ of $W$ is independent of $a$.

One result along these lines comes from a well-known [paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01214191.pdf) of Fremlin and Talagrand. In particular, they show that if $v(a)=0$ for all finite $a \subset W$ and $v$ is measurable with respect to $P$ defined by
$$P(\{a: b \subset a\}) = 2^{-|b|} \ \text{for all finite } b \subset W, \tag{2}$$
then (1) holds for all $a \in 2^W$ (see Lemma 1B and 1J).

Are there generalizations of the Fremlin-Talagrand framework that consider $P$ other than the "iid fair coin" defined in (2)? How can we relax the assumption that $v$ vanishes on finite sets? Any more recent references are appreciated.